# Can't see errors/warnings in Problems view unless project is selected in Package Explorer

Tags: android, eclipse

I can not see any errors or warnings in my Eclipse(4.4.2) unless I specifically select the project or file in Package Explorer and then go to the Problem view.

So far I tried different options in "configure contents" and "show" dialogs in the Problems view menu without success. The only time I see errors in the Problems view is if I set the options "show all" or "all errors" and then it shows every issue with every project I have, don't want/need that.
I also tried (following suggestions from other posts) closing/reopening project, Build Automatically and fix project properties... no luck.

I remember it used to be that if you had issues in a file you were currently editing you could jump straight to the Problems view and it would show you the issues for the project where that file lives, in other words the current project being edited. This is the result I want.

Android SDK manager is up to date so I am out of ideas. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Open the 'Configure Contents' menu and select the 'All Errors' (click the line don't use click the check box). You should then be able to configure the Scope of the errors on the right hand side of the dialog (such as any element in same project)
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately playing with the Scope and configurations did not solve my issue. I want to add that if I hover over the Problems icon on the side, then I get a pop up message correctly indicating I have x errors/warnings in my project. The problem is when I click on the icon the errors/warning disappear.